# Create a desktop shortcut to the shortcut wizard

Tags: shortcuts

Is there anyone out there who knows how to create a desktop shortcut to the create shortcut wizard, rather than the more conventional

RIGHT CLICK > NEW > SHORTCUT

Help

altikaka

Comment: You'd need to give it a context so it sounds like it would be pretty useless as you'd always create the shortcut int the same location? But you could script it: [How do I create a shortcut via command-line in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028709)

Comment: The wizard is a function of explorer.exe